# Wordpress caching query results

Tags: wordpress

I have  a Product (CPT) library and a Partner (CPT) library. Each Product has a Partner assigned to it but not all Partners have Products. I need to produce a `select` for a search that shows only show those Partners that have Products.

This is straightforward in theory, I list all Partners, for each Partner I query Products (through a meta field) and if results are found, I list the Partner (possibly with a count) if not I step over.

However, for several 100 Partners, this is a lot of database queries (to produce a select). It strikes me that it would be good to perform this search once.

Could I put a meta field into each Partner with a product count, I could do this maybe on a Product save. Then I could interogate the meta directly rather than the Product query for each Partner. (Would this be faster?)

How would I do this?

I am currently using (for each Partner);

```
 $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'no_found_rows'  => true,
    'fields'         => 'ids',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key'      => 'partner',
          'value'    => $partner_id,
          'compare' => 'LIKE',
         ),
    ),
 );

 $partner_query = new WP_Query($args);
 if ($partner_query->have_posts() ) :                         
    // Show in Select                    
 endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the number of products per partner this with one query of products and process the results (untested):

```php
function get_partners_with_products() {
    $cache = get_transient( 'partners_with_products' );

    if ( ! empty( $cache ) && is_array( $cache ) ) {
        return $cache;
    }

    // Find all products assigned to partners.
    $products_with_partners = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'no_found_rows'  => true,
        'fields'         => 'ids',
        'meta_key'       => 'partner',
    ) );

    $partners = array();

    // Create an array of partner products, keyed by partner ID.
    foreach ( $products_with_partners->posts as $product_id ) {
        $partner_id = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'partner', true );

        if ( empty( $partner_id ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        if ( ! array_key_exists( $partner_id, $partners ) ) {
            $partners[ $partner_id ] = array();
        }

        $partners[ $partner_id ][] = $product_id;
    }

    // Store the results in a transient for 10 minutes.
    set_transient( 'partners_with_products', $partners, MINUTE_IN_SECONDS * 10 );

    return $partners;
}
```

You may be able to optimize further with a custom SQL query, once you have the product results, but the above should get you started.